# Same data stored in different tables in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, data-storage

I am using Cassandra to store the big data.

In order to run several queries, I am afraid that I need to create different tables and insert almost the same data into these tables.

Will it affect the performance?

What I have done right now is reading one record from the queue, push it into five tables that I created in Cassandra. 
If the records in one table takes about 10M memory, then in five tables, will it take 50M memory in total?
Is there a better way to store duplicated data in Cassandra?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you pushing it to five tables? Surely not duplicating it 5x would save memory, or if not you need to explain what you mean better!

Comment: Because in order to run these queries, I may need to build five tables.

Comment: I know the way I designed column familis is not good. The queries are: select * from a where host in ('nj','ny'); select * from a where user_id in('122','134'); select * from a where module in('Request','Receive'); select * from a order by timestamp; select count(distinct user_id) from a; select count(*) order by timestamp; ... I don't know how to combine them in one table. The parameters within "IN" clause need to be the primary key. If I create multiple primary keys, it always throws exception. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> If I create multiple primary keys, it always throws exception.

That is expected, you cant have multiple primery keys. When you combine columns to make a primary key it's called a composite (or compound) key. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE timeline (
  user_id varchar,
  tweet_id uuid,
  author varchar,
  body varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tweet_id)); // PK consists of two columns!
```

For your data model I would try something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE timeline (
  user_id varchar,
  module varchar,
  host varchar,
  body varchar,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, module, host));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But the primary key needs to be unique, right? So I need to use log_usage_id to be the primary key. One more thing, with the table that you designed above, if I want to run the query"select * from timeline where host = 'nj'", it will throw an exception, since the primary key module has restrictions on host. I can only run the query like "select * from timeline where module = 'getRequest' and host = 'nj'".

Comment: So that's the reason I want to use multiple tables. For select * from table where host in ('nj', 'ny'), my primary key is (log_usage_id, host). As for select * from table where module in('getRequest', 'getResponse'), my primary key is (log_usage_id, module).

Comment: For the compound key, not every row has to be unique. As long as the components of a compound key together are unique, its ok! An example for clarity: We have a key with userid and car_colour, User with id 1 can have a red car, and user with id2 can have a red car. These two elements when combined are unique.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. But in my model, the combination of (user_id, module, host) is not unique. That is why I need to put log_usage_id in the primary key. Could you please look at my another question above? With the table that you designed above, if I want to run the query "select * from timeline where host = 'nj'", it will throw an exception, since the primary key module has restrictions on host. I can only run the query like "select * from timeline where module = 'getRequest' and host = 'nj'". So I want to use multiple tables. Is it possible to use only one table?